# When I use root to open Sublime Text 3, all packages are missing

Tags: linux, debian, root, sublime-text-3

With Sublime Text 3 running under Debian Linux, I have installed several packages as a normal user, but whenever edit any file I have to write the administrator password.

So I used `su` and `subl` to open Sublime Text 3 as `root` so that I don't have to write the `sudo` password each time I edit something – but now all packages are missing. When I return to the normal user, packages are back again.

Why is this happening and what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: i write su in terminal then root password , then i write subl

Comment: @slhck thk for the edit ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When launched from a root shell invoked by `su`, Sublime will think it's running as a different user, thus not find your locally installed packages. To launch Sublime with root privileges, but keep the user environment, do

```
sudo subl
```

If `subl` is not found, use the path of the `sublime_text` executable, e.g. `/usr/bin/subl` or whatever `subl` launches.

If you say you need `root` privileges to edit all your files, you should think about changing the permissions of the files so that your normal user has access to them. If you're editing system files (e.g. in `/etc`), then you'll need `sudo`, but for example for editing code in projects, you need to make sure that the files either belong to you (`chown $(whoami) /path/to/file`) or to the group of your user (`chgrp somegroup /path/to/file`) and that they're group-writable (`chmod g+w /path/to/file`).